# How do I make the console log show the error together instead of on separate lines?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm working with Cloud Functions and I'm trying to debug why my code isn't creating a row in the users collection (although it is successfully creating the new user via Auth). Below is what the error looks like. I think it has something to do with my timestamp, but I can't even read the full error properly. How can I capture the error and store it into a variable, then output it in one line in the console log?

[image]

```
exports.newUserSignup = functions.auth.user().onCreate(user => {
  console.log('user created', user.email, user.uid);
  const doc = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc();
  return doc.set({
    createDate: admin.firestore.Timestamp,
    modifiedDate: admin.firestore.Timestamp, 
    username: 'blah',
    email: user.email,    
    stat: 1,
    uid: user.uid,
    rowpointer: doc.id,
  });
});
```

I've tried both `admin.firestore.Timestamp` and `admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp`. Both gave errors.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it solves your exact problem, but Firebase's Cloud Functions nowadays has a built-in custom function for logging. Using this typically means they show up in a more readable format in the logs.

To use these:

> ```
> const functions = require("firebase-functions");
>
> functions.logger.log("Hello from info. Here's an object:", someObj);
> ```

For more on this, see the Firebase documentation on [writing and viewing logs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs).